# php ignore redirect if statement

Tags: php, html, forms, if-statement, redirect

I'm making a register form with various input fields. I have a validation code for when 1 field is empty and also a validation code for when de whole form is empty. When the form is empty, it will redirect back to the register page. But if i fill out 1 input field, he still runs the empty form redirect instead of ignoring that one and continue to the next if statement.

Can you guys help me out please?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form class="register form" action="../app/controller/authController.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="region" id="">
                    <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
                    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="" placeholder="First Name">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['FN_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['FN_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['FN_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="" placeholder="Last Name">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['LN_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['LN_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['LN_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['EA_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['EA_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['EA_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="confirm_email" id="" placeholder="Confirm E-mail Address">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['Confirm_email_error'])) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['Confirm_email_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['Confirm_email_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="" placeholder="Password">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['PS_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['PS_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['PS_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['Confirm_pass_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['Confirm_pass_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['Confirm_pass_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="age" id="" placeholder="Age">
                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['AGE_error'] )) : ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['AGE_error']; ?></span>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['AGE_error']); endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="type" value="Register" class="register button">
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

if ($_POST['type'] == 'Register') {

    if (trim($_POST['first_name']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['FN_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['last_name']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['LN_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['email']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['EA_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['password']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['PS_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['age']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['AGE_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['confirm_email']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['Confirm_email_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    } elseif($_POST['email'] != $_POST['confirm_email']) {
        $_SESSION['Confirm_email_error'] = "E-mail Address does not match!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }

    if (trim($_POST['confirm_password']) == "") {
        $_SESSION['Confirm_pass_error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    } elseif($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']) {
        $_SESSION['Confirm_pass_error'] = "Password does not match!";
        $user->redirect('register.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: You can use session
http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question! What you want is this: If all the fields are empty, then redirect to the `register.php`. But if only one field(any field) is empty and all other fields are filled, then continue? Did I understand you correct?

Comment: mostly, yes. when all the fields are empty, redirect to `register.php`. but for example if you fill in the **first_name** field, and don't fill in the **last_name** field, I want it to run the **last_name** validation and say the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
    $i=0;
    $names=array('first_name', 'last_name','email','password','age','confirm_email');
    foreach($names as $field) {
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $_SESSION[$field.'error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";
        $i++;
      }
      else
      {
          unset($_SESSION[$field.'error']);
      }
    }
    if(sizeof($names)==$i)
    {   
        $user->redirect('register.php');
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: This still isn't working. When all fields are empty, it redirects to `register.php`, but when I fill in one or more fields, the `$_SESSION[$field.'error'] = "Field cannot be empty!";` does not work.

Comment: try action="" in form tag and change session variable names FN_error as first_nameerror, LN_error as last_nameerror. Because session variables are generating dynamically in above PHP script.